# Create a list of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a loop to read every tables on sql and create each table as a dataframe

```
for data in table_list:
    df = d.read_sql_query('select * from ' + data[0], con)
```

for example,

```
table_list = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

and what i want to achieve is to have a list form every dataframes.

expected output, with only names of dataframe, so i can call it in another function:

```
df_list = [df_a, df_b, df_c]
```

is there any best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
df_list = []
for data in table_list:
    df = d.read_sql_query('select * from ' + data[0], con)
    df_list.append(df)
```

Comment: yes it works, but how can i have this output: df_list = [df_a, df_b, df_c], with only a name it it, so i  can call it in another function

Comment: @Laz! , yes just make a dictionary, one item is your df and another item is the name; and finally make a list of dictionaries (consisting from datarame and its name), not a list of data frames.

Or simply, you can add a new column to your data frames and put the name of the dataframe inside one of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go for a dict here instead of list (as per you comment in the Answer by @Mohammed Mos3d)

To do that,

```
df_dict = dict()
for data in table_list:
    df_dict[data] = d.read_sql_query(f"select * from {data}", con)
```

Now, if you want to use a particular data, you can reference the dict by the key,

```
df_dict['a']
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can address :

```
df_list = []
for x in range(len(table_list)):
    df_list.append(f'df_{x}')
```